# What is difference between Pointer of Array and Array of Pointer in c language?

Tags: c, programming-languages

Please tell me what is the difference between Array of Pointer and Pointer to Array, specially in c language

Comment: Are you sure you mean "pointer of an array" and *not* pointer *to* an array? :)

Comment: One points to a collection of things, one is a collection of things that point to other things (aka a collection of pointers).

Answer (score 0):

Let T be a random type (int, long int, double, enum ecc..) then:

```
int n=3;
T arr[n];
T*p=arr;
```

`p` is a pointer to the first elemente of T array `arr`so you can access the first element of your array like this:

```
arr[0]="whatever you want but a r-value"
```

or

```
p=...
```

It's an easy way to move around your array without indexes and a great solution to pass variables by value. Keep in mind that the pointer has, as r-value, the l-value of the pointed object, when the pointer is dereferenced  we obtain the pointed object. So writing p+1 means to move the pointer to the second element of your array.
Arrays of pointers actually are a collection of this object (a pointer to a variable or to another data structure). For example you can have an array of int pointers to track all the elements of a lined list. Since you did not define each pointer, thay are unreferred so it can be a dangerous way to code.